# Lock Boolean Value though while block

Tags: c#, while-loop, boolean, console-application

I am creating a card game and I wish to create a god mode to freak out my friends but I need to keep a Boolean value through all runs of the methods i'm using

All Code:

```
namespace Card_Game_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                P1Hand();
            }

        }


        #region PosAns
        static string PosAns()
        {
            string posans = "Y";
            return posans;
        }
        #endregion


        #region NegAns
        static string NegAns()
        {
            string posans = "N";
            return posans;
        }
        #endregion


        #region P1Hand
        static int P1Hand()
        {
            int P1Hand = 0;
            if (PlayerInput().Equals(PosAns()))
            {
                int NewRnd = Rnd();
                string StringRnd = NewRnd.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(StringRnd);
                P1Hand = P1Hand + NewRnd;
                Console.WriteLine("You're Hand Is " + P1Hand);
            }
            else
            {
                if (GMActP1() == true)
                {
                    P1Hand = GodModeP1();
                    Console.WriteLine("You're Hand Is " + P1Hand);
                }
                if (PlayerInput().Equals(NegAns()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You're Hand Is " +P1Hand);
                }

            }

            return P1Hand;
        }
        #endregion


        #region P2Hand
        static int P2Hand()
        {
            // Not completing till P1 is done
            return P2Hand;
        }
        #endregion


        #region NormalMode
        static int Rnd()
        {
            Random Rd = new Random();            
            int[] Cards = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
            int RandomIdex = Rd.Next(1, Cards.Length);
            return RandomIdex;
        }
        #endregion


        #region GodMString
        static string GodMString()
        {
            string GmAct = " ChTy";
            return GmAct;
        }
        #endregion


        #region GodModeP1
        static int GodModeP1()
        {
            int NewP1Hand = P1Hand();
            int WinHand = 21 - NewP1Hand;
            return WinHand;
        }
        #endregion


        #region GMActP1
        static bool GMActP1()
        {
            bool Godmode = false;
            if (PlayerInput().Equals(PosAns() + GodMString()))
            {
                Godmode = true;

            }
            bool NewGodM = Godmode;
            return NewGodM;            
        }
        #endregion


        #region GodModeP2
        static int GodModeP2()
        {
            int NewP2Hand = P2Hand();
            int WinHand = 21 - NewP2Hand;
            return WinHand;
        }
        #endregion


        #region PlayerInput
        static string PlayerInput()
        {
            string S = Console.ReadLine();

            return S;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now My Problem is this:

1: when the logic turns in the direction of God Mode methods or GM methods it draws a blank then ask for another PlayerInput Method

2: I believe this stems from the Boolean value in GMActP1 Method not staying true through while statements or not returning a value at all so it falls out of the logic in P1Hand Method

the methods are only there till i'm finishing up as it helps me keep track of things so it's easier to edit then when finished I edit it to be a little less crazy. GMString works as the password while GMActP1 is an activator for God Mode for use with Logic in P1Hand.

Here's Where the problem lies:

```
   static bool GMActP1()
    {
        bool Godmode = false;
        Console.WriteLine(Godmode);
        if (PlayerInput().Equals(PosAns() + GodMString()))
        {
            Godmode = true;
            Console.WriteLine(Godmode);

        }
        bool NewGodM = Godmode;
        Console.WriteLine(NewGodM);
        return NewGodM;            
    }
```

I checked the last piece of code and it returns false at all stages.
Here is my question is it possible to lock the bool var as true after the required logic has been met i would rather not have to declare the bool var as false every time it runs because that would mean you would have to write "Y ChTy" every turn you have and if you dont want your friends to know, it wont be very easy to get them to look the other way when you input this "cheat code" when i get this to work i will have it run normally for the first few rounds until the required number to 21 is less than 12 because 12 is the max # card you can receive. This way it looks like a normal game stacked in your favor.

Comment: Why don't you use a globally declared variable then?

Comment: i could but i believe that my problem lies where it's trying to return the value after the if statement. i also want to only activate godmode after the string has been typed like so: Y ChTy. so i can't declare it as true either because then it's always on i also want it only for one player. so if player 1 types it in they have god mode but not player 2. now that i think of it i could put that into logic may be able to bypass the Boolean value all together.

Comment: Use breakpoints then to find out, if your bool variables have the value you expect them to have

Comment: it's returning nothing but false at all stages.

Comment: Look at this condition then: `PlayerInput().Equals(PosAns() + GodMString())`. Why doesn't it determine to true?

Comment: you make the variable `bool Godmode = false;` local.... Of course its false everywhere

Comment: well this string makes the condition PlayerInput().Equals(PosAns() + GodMString()) true "Y ChTy" and what it's receiving is exactly that but it still gives a false it may be the return but it shouldn't be, because the if statement, when true should make the value true and then it returns to the method

Comment: the variable bool Godmode = false; should only remain false until the if statement is true then it should be declared as true locally.

Comment: PlayerInput().Equals(PosAns() + GodMString()); This method will true only where input is "Y ChTy" and after that method will return true. I checked it and it's working. Where are you facing problem?